# How to plot histogram of string and float value of a csv file using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I need to show the histogram of a specific attribute of a csv file. When I plot numeric values I have no problems, but when I use string values the program crashes.
Now I'm using the iris dataset for testing, the program crashes when I select the 'species' column. The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Enrico\PycharmProjects\PythonDataset\Plot_hist.py", line 31, 
  in <lambda> self.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: 
  self.plotHistogram(fileName))
File "C:\Users\Enrico\PycharmProjects\PythonDataset\Plot_hist.py", line 50, 
  in plotHistogram data_file[attribute].plot(kind='hist')
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2741, in 
  __call__ **kwds)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 2002, in 
  plot_series **kwds)
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 1804, in 
  _plot plot_obj.generate()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 258, in 
  generate self._compute_plot_data()
File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\plotting\_core.py", line 373, in 
  _compute_plot_data 'plot'.format(numeric_data.__class__.__name__))
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

My code is this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def plotHistogram(self, file):
    attribute = str(self.comboBox.currentText())
    data_file = pd.read_csv(file)
    data_file[attribute].plot(kind='hist')
    plt.ylabel('Frequency')
    plt.xlabel(attribute)
    plt.title("File")
    plt.show()
```

`attribute`is the column name, `file` is the csv file.

Note:
If I change `data_file[attribute].plot(kind='hist')` into `data_file[attribute].hist()`
the program doesn't crash, but after a long time it plots a strange histogram.

EDIT:
I have to show the histogram of laboratory analysis values, from csv files that have 20 to 30 attributes and more than a thousand lines.
I need to show the histogram of the values ​​of each attribute taken individually, but the values ​​can be numeric data or strings.
On the x axis I have to have the scale of the values ​​from the minimum to the maximum and on that of the y the frequency, as in this example:[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gBrJILp7_ixfXg6ub4semkTqCjN2OmmE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot plot a histogram of strings. What you're probably looking for is a bar plot where the height of the bar represents the frequency of occurence of the respective strings. This could be done via `value_counts()`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"num" : np.random.randint(20, size=250),
                  "str" : np.random.choice(["cat", "dog", "pig"], 
                                           size=250, p=[.2,.3,.5])})

df["str"].value_counts().plot.bar()

plt.show()
```

[image]

If you want to let this *look* more similar to a numeric histogram, you could set the width to 1

```
df["str"].value_counts().plot.bar(width=1)
```

[image]

Comment: But i can insert in pd.DataFrame the csv file, like this "df = pd.DataFrame(data_file)" ?

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(df)` gives the same dataframe as `df`, not sure what purpose that would serve. If you want to copy a DataFrame you can do that via `df2 = df.copy()`.

Comment: A histogram is not defined for strings, so if the above is not what you're after, you would need to describe what you are aiming at. Concerning the order, you may use [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html). Concerning "too many values", again, how would you like it to look intead?

Comment: Sorry I still can not upload images, I put the link of the image loaded on drive, this is what I would like to get, only I need to have the accuracy of 6 numbers after the comma

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the difference, especially since the image shows numbers, for which a histogram is well defined. I updated the answer with what I could imagine to be the issue now.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I understand, I can check the type of data and even decide whether to use the function hist() or bar().